# Confusion regarding package minimongo/mongo in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am thinking that might already be answered but I cannot find anything.

What is the difference between the minimongo/monog atmosphere packages and what is already supplied in Meteor?

I added them in early on and I was wondering if they are still needed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

minimongo is a dependency of mongo, and mongo is definitely part of the meteor package
so yes, it is part of the distribution.

if I run meteor show minimongo I get:

```
meteor show minimongo                                                                                                                                   master 
Package: minimongo@1.0.10                     
Maintainers: mdg                              
Exports: LocalCollection, Minimongo           

`minimongo` is reimplementation of (almost) the entire MongoDB API, against an
in-memory JavaScript database. It is like a MongoDB emulator that runs inside
your web browser. You can insert data into it and search, sort, and update that
data. This is great if you like the MongoDB API (which you may already be using
on the server), need a way to store data on the client that you've fetched and
are using to render your interface, and want to use that familiar API.

Minimongo is used as a temporary data cache in the standard Meteor stack, to
learn more about mini-databases and what they can do, see [the project page on
www.meteor.com](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases)

Recent versions:                              
  1.0.6   December 19th, 2014                 
  1.0.7   March 17th, 2015
  1.0.8   March 31st, 2015      installed
  1.0.9   September 21st, 2015  installed
  1.0.10  September 28th, 2015  installed

Older and pre-release versions of minimongo have been hidden. To see all 56 versions, run 'meteor show --show-all minimongo'.
```